# How is it possible to minimize a definite integral, if there are three parameters that can be varied in the integrand?

Tags: functional-equations, maxima-minima, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I have been attempting to minimize the following integral:

$$
T=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\frac{1+y'^2}{2gy}}dx,
$$

knowing that $y$ is of the form:
$$
y = a_0 +a_1 x+a_2x^2 
$$
and that $y(0)=2$ and $y(\pi)=0$. I don't know that it is possible to solve the integral analytically, and so I have been thinking that I should use the Euler-Lagrange differential equation (see [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDifferentialEquation.html) for details).

The trouble is, that I've found $a_2$ as a function of $x$, by recognizing $a_0=2$ and $a_1=-\Big(\frac{2}{\pi}+\pi a_2\Big)$ and substituting everything into the Euler-Lagrange differential equation, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Is there any other way to solve such a problem? Am I just messing up a calculation somewhere? I'm working in Python, which has been making it difficult to keep track of variables, so it may be that the latter is in fact true.

I would appreciate very much any help in figuring this out.

Comment: Could you tell what is $g$ ?

Comment: The Euler-Lagrange equation is useful if your unknown is a function (i.e. if you're doing variational calculus). Here your unknowns are three scalars. What you need to do instead is compute the derivatives $dT/da_i$ using differentiation under the integral sign and set them to zero.

Comment: This may also be too hard to find an analytical solution, and you may have to resort to numerical methods.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: $g$ is in this case a constant.

Comment: @Rahul: so because there is a single unknown scalar after accounting for initial conditions, what you're saying is that I can differentiate with respect to $a_2$ (in this case), and set the resultant intergrand to zero, to solve for $a_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To optimize something, you differentiate it with respect to the unknown(s) and set the derivative to zero. // Only if your unknown was the function $y$ whose form was unknown, then it's non-obvious how to differentiate with respect to a function, and *that's* what the Euler-Lagrange equation is for.